# How to parse a response from API query (in JSON {"key":value} format) into a list of variables so that it can be input into a SQL table?

Tags: python, sql, json

I am using Python's requests module to query an API to retrieve information, which comes in the form of a JSON object like: `{"key":value, "key": value, "key": value, etc.}`. There are multiple `key:value` pairs, and the values are either strings, integers, or floats. I would like to put this information into a SQL table, where the "key" corresponds to a column heading and the "value" corresponds to an entry in that column. How can I parse a JSON object, so that it instead of being in `{"key":value}` format, the "key" becomes a variable with the value "value"? In other words:

From: `{"key":value}`

To: `key = value`

The code for querying the API looks like:

```
req = requests.get('URL')
```

If I convert it into text, so you can see the JSON object from the API query looks like:

```
print(data)
print(type(data))
```

What gets returned is in the form of this:

```
[{"key1":19.0,"key2":"D4AE057C1E4A","key3":-66,"key4":1530240344}]
<class 'str'>
```

***What do I need to do to get it to look like:***

```
key1=19.0, 
key2="D4AE057C1E4A",
key3:-66,
key4:1530240344
```

?? I need the data to be in the form of variables, so that I can then put it into my code for inputting the object as a row into the table in the SQL database. That code looks like:

```
session = examples.get_session('name_of_database', 'name_of_user')


x=examples.name_of_table(key1=19,key2="D4AE057C1E4A",key3=-66,key4=1530240344)
session.add(x)
session.commit()
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import json
data = json.loads('[{"key1":19.0,"key2":"D4AE057C1E4A","key3":-66,"key4":1530240344}]')
for key,value in data[0].items():
    exec("%s = '%s'" % (key,value))
```

This iterates through the dict, and creates variables from the key names

Comment: getting an error message: "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Comment: Updated. You have to convert the data to a dict with `json.loads()` and then get the items from that.